Artifactory Dependency not recognised in Android
I have a number of old third party dependencies in our app, some of which are hosted on jcenter() .  I decided that an approach would be to move these to a maven repo in artifactory and add the dependencies to that. One of the libraries is com.kaopiz.kprogresshud
I have done that, successfully (I think) as I can see the dependency in the dependency tree when I run ./gradlew app:dependencies and I can see the lib in the package explorer when in package view.

The problem I have is that the library is now not recognised in the application e.g.  
I have cleared the cache and restarted android studio, I have also deleted the imports and tried to reimport but none of that works.

Most likely you are talking about com.kaopiz:kprogresshud which was hostes on JCenter, but now it is gone: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.kaopiz/kprogresshud?repo=jcenter Just click on the aar links, they are all dead. JCenter has been shut down years ago: https://blog.gradle.org/jcenter-shutdown

I know.  I stated that as a result of that being hosted on jcenter I wanted to host it on artifactory.  So I created an artifact, using the jar in the gradle cache.  I have done that and successfully retrieved it as a dependency from jfrog, which I can see in the package explorer.. however the application is not recognising it.  So in the classes it is used the imports don't work
